# Вместо уменьшение самого изображения, уменьшается область видимости

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.iconBold{
    background: url("../images/blod.png") no-repeat;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a ><span class="iconBold"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что надо ещё размер фона задать - background-size: cover или background-size: 100%

Comment: спасибо,правильно

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в стиль способ масштабирования

```
.iconBold {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

подробней: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size